# Session_Start running for specific page, creating new sessionid

Tags: asp.net-4.0, global-asax

We have one page that is causing the Session_start to run and I cannot figure out why.  Anytime home.aspx is called, Session_start in global.asax is called and a new sessionid is created.

The sessionid looks to be created right when session_start is called.  I think that is normal.  I just don't know why it is called all from this page.

Home.aspx uses a different master page than the others.  I have not found anything in it that is causing this.  I checked the Response.Redirect calls, because others have indicated that could be the issue.  I found none being called.

Using firebug, I found this:
Server  Microsoft-IIS/5.1
.
.

```
Location    /ent4_sql/(S(unfzfplfp5ltgxcrtpt2bk3f))/Home.aspx?_TSM_HiddenField_=ctl00_ctl04_HiddenField&_TSM_CombinedScripts_=%3b%3bAjaxControlToolkit%2c+Version%3d4.1.40412.0%2c+Culture%3dneutral%2c+PublicKeyToken%3d28f01b0e84b6d53e%3aen-US%3aacfc7575-cdee-46af-964f-5d85d9cdcf92%3ade1feab2%3af9cec9bc%3aa67c2700%3af2c8e708%3a8613aea7%3a3202a5a2%3aab09e3fe%3a87104b7c%3abe6fb298
```

The session in the url is different than the one that is displayed in the browser address bar.  The browser seems to always keep the original.

From searching the web, this issue seems to be one that doesn't really have a direct answers.  I am just out of things to look for. Any suggestions would be helpful.

Update***
Using fiddler, I found that the system is actually going to ent4_sql/Home.aspx?.....

Notice the session is not in the URL
That displays a page

```
<html><head><title>Object moved</title></head><body>
<h2>Object moved to <a href="/ent4_sql/(S(bzbos0dmqfcw34wiljuybu2u))/Home.aspx?_TSM_HiddenField_=ctl00_ctl04_HiddenField&amp;_TSM_CombinedScripts_=%3b%3bAjaxControlToolkit%2c+Version%3d4.1.40412.0%2c+Culture%3dneutral%2c+PublicKeyToken%3d28f01b0e84b6d53e%3aen-US%3aacfc7575-cdee-46af-964f-5d85d9cdcf92%3ade1feab2%3af9cec9bc%3aa67c2700%3af2c8e708%3a8613aea7%3a3202a5a2%3aab09e3fe%3a87104b7c%3abe6fb298">here</a>.</h2>
</body></html>
```

and seems to redirect whatever is calling that to a url with session.  I am trying to find more information on if others have seen the AjaxControlToolkit doing this.

Comment: We have found that issue has to do with ModalPopupExtender.  Any page that has these is doing a redirect through the scriptresource.axd.  Because we have our session state set to cookieless="true", the session id value is not being added to to the url and the session is being dropped and recreated.  Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem had to do with the Ajax Control Toolkit and cookieless sessions, as expected.  Here is an issue reported in 2009 dealing with the same problem.  Fix is now included on the issue

http://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/workitem/23443